# How to add Group in mounting drive in fstab

Tags: ubuntu, fstab

I am using this to mount drive at startup

```
/dev/sda5 /media/virtual ntfs defaults,umask=700,uid=1 0 0
```

This is working fine but i need things

1)By this method all the folders inside the virtual folder have same permissions but i want 700 for virtual directory and 777 for all other directories

2)I want that if i can add group as well in the mount command. Just like uid, if i couol add gid as well. Is it possible

Answer (score 3):

[Uhh...](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.ntfs-3g)

> uid=value and gid=value
>
> > Set the owner and the group of files and directories. The values are numerical. The defaults are the uid and gid of the current process.
> >
> > ...
>
> fmask=value
>
> > Set the bitmask of the file permissions that are not present. The value is given in octal. The default value is 0 which means full access to everybody.
>
> dmask=value
>
> > Set the bitmask of the directory permissions that are not present. The value is given in octal. The default value is 0 which means full access to everybody.

Comment: Thanks , it get it working. But i still have one problem. IN my partition "virtual" , i have five folders , i only want to give the 777 access to one folder but to others i need 700 permission. How can i do permissions different for different folders. I don't want anyone to see other folders

Comment: That can't be done. The granularity of permissions for non-POSIX-compliant filesystems is the entire volume.

Comment: then , can i change permission after mounting. These has to have some solution.

Answer (score 1):

/dev/sda5 /media/virtual ntfs defaults,umask=700,uid=1,gid=1 0 0

Just adding gid= to the options should add the group of your choice .. though I'd ensure your using the right GID. Setting umask to 777 will effect all files and dirs mounted.

T